# posts as children of wp_list_pages item

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a vertical menu that looks like this

```
HOME
NEWS
ANOTHER PAGE
- SUB PAGE
- SUB PAGE
```

it is retrieved via wp_list_pages. NEWS is set as my posts page in the WP backend.

what i want to achieve is getting the titles of the 3 latest posts to show up as a submenu of NEWS like so:

```
HOME
NEWS
- POST 3
- POST 2
- POST 1
ANOTHER PAGE
- SUB PAGE
- SUB PAGE
```

is there some sort of add_filter/function or even plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks as if you're trying to use a Page Object as a sort of "shell" for corresponding posts. This is probably one of the first traps a Wordpress Developer will find themselves in when developing their own themes, or working with existing code.

In short, you shouldn't use wp_list_pages if you're trying to also list Post Objects. It gets messy, and you're essentially circumventing existing methods that Wordpress provides to do exactly what you need.

What you'll want to do is look into is the built-in [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen) to build out a more flexible menu. If you're using a downloaded theme, then it will almost certainly be supported. Otherwise, you'll need to look into [Registering a Navigation Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) to make your theme "menu-aware".

What this will enable you to do is build a flexible menu that supports not only Pages, but also Categories and individual Posts in an intuitive UI. I would suggest deleting that Page Object called "News" altogether, and instead place the News Category in your menu alongside all of your Page Objects in whatever order you like.

As for querying the most recent three posts in your Navigation Menu as sub-menus, this will be a little more complicated to do with pure code.

What I would suggest is to look into this option first. Build out a working - albeit static - prototype to get a feel for the Menu Interface. If you're writing your own theme, replace your wp_list_pages call altogether with [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Once you get that working, open a new question to see how to write your own [Nav Menu Walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039) to make everything display exactly how you want.

By taking this approach, you'll ensure that your theme will ALWAYS behave how you want automatically, rather than having to go in every so often to patch things up.

Let me know if this helps.